# How to compile RoR code in Notepad++?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compilation, notepad++

I tried this [*tutorial*](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2010/06/16/start-learning-ruby-with-ironruby-setting-up-the-environment.aspx) but it didn't give me any output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby is not a compiled language, but an interpreted one. If you want to get an output, you can run `irb` (Interactive Ruby Shell) in the command line, and enter the code in line-by-line or run it in the command line as `ruby FILE_NAME.rb`. This should provide the output you are looking for. In my opinion and experience, the command line is the best way to work with ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is plain ruby code, you should follow [this article (Notepad++ with C#)](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/notepad-c-compiler-you-can-do) and replace the compiler with the Ruby compiler like [RubyScriptToExe](http://www.erikveen.dds.nl/rubyscript2exe/), or to the ruby command line interpreter